# Not a managed type: class com.sharesmiles.model.User

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
package com.sharesmiles.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
```

```
package com.sharesmiles;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {“com.sharesmiles”})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {“com.sharesmiles.repository”})
@EntityScan(”com.sharesmiles.model“)
public class ShareSmilesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShareSmilesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sharesmiles.repository;

import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.sharesmiles.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

```
package com.sharesmiles.service;
import com.sharesmiles.model.User;
import com.sharesmiles.repository.UserRepository;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, User> userRedisTemplate;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    
    private boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
        return (password.length() >= 6);
    }
    // 用户注册方法。
    public User userRegister(User user) {
        // 1. 检查username的格式
        if (!isValidName(user.getUsername()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username is not valid");

        // 2.检查email的格式
        if (!isValidEmail(user.getEmail()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email is not valid");
        
        // 3. 检查password的格式
        if (!isValidPassword(user.getPassword()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password is not valid");

        // 4. 检查email是否已经被使用
        Optional<User> existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (existingUser.isPresent()) 
            // 非法状态异常，newEmail参数本身有效，但又有数据库状态，我们无法继续使用
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already in use");
        
        // 处理与注册相关的业务逻辑，例如密码哈希、验证输入等。
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(hashedPassword);

        // 处理完上述逻辑后，将user保存用户信息到数据库
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sharesmiles.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sharesmiles.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.sharesmiles.model.User;
import com.sharesmiles.service.UserService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // 以POST方法发送到/api/users/register的HTTP请求
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User user) {
        User registeredUser = userService.userRegister(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(registeredUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version> 
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.4</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

when I run mvn spring-boot:run“ in terminal, it show me the error message like “org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.sharesmiles.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ShareSmilesApplication: Not a managed type: class com.sharesmiles.model.User

would you mind provide some help about this issue?

Comment: What version of `Spring` do you use? If it is 6+ then you should jakarta.persistence.* package instead of javax.persistence.*

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your annotations on your Spring Boot main class, it appears that many of these are unnecessary. Because the entity, repository, service classes all hang off of the same package structure as ShareSmilesApplication.java you really only need @SpringBootApplication like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ShareSmilesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShareSmilesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

You didn't include your Controller code but I'm wondering if it's possible your repository is getting wired first with @EnableJpaRepositories before your User Entity is getting wired with EntityScan. You could try changing the order in your annotations but I'd first try with just @SpringBootApplication.

Edit:

I suspect the issue is with mixing the Javax Peristence dependency with the Spring Boot Starter Data JPA dependency that comes with jakarta.persistence.

I ran your project locally and removed the Javax Persistence dependency and refactored the User entity to use jakarta.persistence and the entity got wired up correctly.

Comment: Hi Timur, hope you are doing well.
I try with just @SpringBootApplication, and then try EntityScan before enableJpaRepository, but it did not work as well. btw, I edit the question and attach the Controller code.

Comment: Hi Yanting. Please see my edit. If you have legacy code that needs to be on javax then you probably need to just use that and not mix it with a newer version of spring boot starter data jpa that is using jakarta.persistence. If this is a new project I would just go with spring boot starter data jpa and remove the other persistence dependencies from your pom.